# How to checked and unchecked values of checkboxes with same name two different places using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have checkboxes with same name two different places, like below

**One place**

```
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="1" type="checkbox" />
```

**Second place**

```
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="1" type="checkbox" />
```

updated my question, plz check once, actually one place first checkbox value same and 5th checkbox value same, so whichever checkbox select that checkbox only select, in this case both value 1 checked.

what i want is , if i select value 1 of one place automatically it selects second place value 1 and also seletc second place value 1 automatically it will select first place value 1 checkbox select using jquery , plz help me.

```
 var vtypeid = [];
        $.each($("input[name='vtypeid']:checked"), function(){    
            vtypeid.push($(this).val());

        });
```

any one using this code how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting based on `name="checkbox-group"` in case there are other checkboxes on the page that aren't part of this functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cbs = $('input[name="checkbox-group"]').click(function() {
    cbs.filter(($(this).is(".place1") ? ".place2" : ".place1")
               + '[value="' + this.value + '"]')
       .prop('checked', this.checked)  
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First group:
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="5" type="checkbox" />
<br><br>
Second group:
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="5" type="checkbox" />
```

Note: for checkboxes I recommend the click event rather than the change event, because the latter behaves a bit weirdly for keyboard input in some older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `change` event to `class` `place1` and `place2` and using `value` attribute you can check and uncheck the checkboxes in different places.

```
$(".place1").change(function () {
   $("input[value=" + $(this).attr("value") + "].place2").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$(".place2").change(function () {
    $("input[value=" + $(this).attr("value") + "].place1").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.place1[name=checkbox-group]").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      $("input.place2[value="+$(this).val()+"]").prop('checked', true);
    }
    else{
      $("input.place2[value="+$(this).val()+"]").prop('checked', false);
    }
      
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 1st
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="2" type="checkbox" />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="3" type="checkbox" />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="4" type="checkbox" />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="5" type="checkbox" />
</div>

<div> 2nd
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="2" type="checkbox" />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="3" type="checkbox" />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="4" type="checkbox" />
  <input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="5" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: selecting the `input` having class `place2` with `value` equal to clicked `input`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do. it is one of the way

```js
$('[name = checkbox-group]').on('click', function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   $('[name = checkbox-group][value='+val+']').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place1" value="5" type="checkbox" />

   <br />
second
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="1" type="checkbox"  />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="4" type="checkbox" />
<input name="checkbox-group" class="place2" value="5" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put this code its working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"][name=checkbox-group]').change(function () {
            $("input[name=checkbox-group][value='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

give unique id do like this

```
 <input name="checkbox-group" id="chk1" class="place1" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('chk2').checked = this.checked;" />


    <input name="checkbox-group_1" id="chk2" class="place2" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('chk1').checked = this.checked;" />
```

Comment: But...then you'd have to have separate click handlers for every checkbox. Isn't that a lot of trouble?